# Iterate layerScope.variable

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I have a problem with this code :

```
for layer in layers :
   #surcharge avec le filtre permanent
   if QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer).variable('layer_filter')!=None:
     sql=u"(" + sql + u") AND " + QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer).variable('layer_filter')
```

When a variable is found it is added to the sql variable. It is however kept for every layer even if there is no filter variable for them.

What can be done so the SQL filter corresponds to a single layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `else` clause that puts an empty string in `sql`